# Call from dynamicly created child constructor function to parent constructur

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, this, parent

Update: I updated the code from a answer and it's working now. Thanks to @Azamantes

I try to call the parent object/constructor.

HTML Code:

```
<div style="width:50px; height: 50px; display: inline-block; background-color:red;" id="id0">BoxId0</div>
<div style="width:50px; height: 50px; display: inline-block; background-color:red;" id="id1">BoxId1</div>
<div style="width:50px; height: 50px; display: inline-block; background-color:red;" id="id2">BoxId2</div>
<div style="width:50px; height: 50px; display: inline-block; background-color:red;" id="id3">BoxId3</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
    function Child(parent, childID) {
            var thisReference = this;
            var parentReference = parent;

            $(childID).on("click", function() {
                parentReference.childCallMe(childID); // Gave on click 'TypeError: parentReference.childCallMe is not a function'
            });

            return {
                getParent() { return parentReference },
                getThis() { return thisReference },
                getChild() { return childID },
            }
        }


        function Mother(childrenCount) {
            var thisReference = this;
            var children = [];
            var testText = "test";

// Will not work:            
function childCallMe(id) {
                alert("mohter: " + id);
            }
// This will work:
this.childCallMe = function(id){ alert('mother' + id) };

            for(var i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++) {
                children[i] = new Child(thisReference, '#id' + i);
            }

            return {
                getTestText() { return testText },
                getThis() { return thisReference },
                getChildren() { return children },
            };
        };
    /*
        Mother.prototype.childCallMe = function(id) {
            alert(id);
            //I need to call a function in Mother
        };
    */

        var mother1 = new Mother(4);
```

I will reuse the 'mother' more times for different HTML Elements. The count of 'childs' can change too. I think I'm not clear how to use the this-context. In PHP it's very simple. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Child(parent, childID) {
    var thisReference = this;

    $(childID).on("click", function() {
        parent.childCallMe(childID); // Gives 'TypeError: parent.childCallMe is not a function'
    });

    return {
        getThis() { return thisReference },
        getChild() { return childID },
    }
}


function Mother(childrenCount) {
    var thisReference = this;
    var children = [];

    function childCallMe(id) {
        alert(id);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++) {
        children[i] = new Child(this, '#id' + i);
    }

    return { 
        getThis() { return thisReference },
        getChildren() { return children },
    };
};
Mother.prototype.childCallMe = function(id) {
    alert(id);
};

var mother1 = new Mother(4);
```

So, after refining your code a bit I noticed you didn't add the `childCallMe` method from the Mother 'class' and so Child didn't see it and hence the error.

Here is the way it makes the most sense:

```
function Child(parent, childID) {
    this.id = childID;

    $(childID).on("click", function() {
        parent.childCallMe(childID); // Gives 'TypeError: parent.childCallMe is not a function'
    });
}


function Mother(childrenCount) {
    this.children = [];

    function childCallMe(id) {
        alert(id);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++) {
        this.children[i] = new Child(this, '#id' + i);
    }
};
Mother.prototype.childCallMe = function(id) {
    alert(id);
};

var mother1 = new Mother(4);
```

Comment: I changed to 'var api = { childCallMe : childCallMe,', no changes, same error. If I use in the child on the click event 'alert(objParent.toSource());' I get an empty Object: '({})'.

Comment: Now it works. I added the `Mother.prototype.childCallMe` method on the bottom. It didn't work because the way you create the Mother object doesn't allow it to keep the reference to the function (because you return the function after creating the Child objects. You could do that in another way, but anyways, that's what `prototypes` in Javascript are for.

Comment: Thanks! The nasty prototypes :)

Comment: Ok, what I finaly want, is to call every Child, after one Child has a event. I tried **'alert(thisReference);'** in the **Mother.prototype.childCallMe**, but I get a **'ReferenceError: thisReference is not defined'**. I also tried **'this', 'getThis()'**. This prototype.childCallMe is like a simple function with no access to the Mother Object.

Comment: Generally if you create variable inside Mother function like `var thisReference = this;` then you cannot access this variable from `Mother.prototype.childCallMe` method. Methods created with `prototype` can access only properties assigned via `this.someProperty = someValue;`. If you want to access Mother object from inside Child object, then you can simply do `alert(parent);` inside the `click event`, since you pass it (the Mother object) as argument (`parent`) to the Child constructor.

Comment: If I remove the prototype and use **parent.childCallMe(childID);** in the click event, I get **TypeError: parent.childCallMe is not a function**. But I have a function called **childCallMe(id)** in **Mother**.

Comment: :) You create a function inside the Mother object indeed, but it stays private, you have to attach it to the Mother object, so instead of `function childCallMe(id) {
            alert("mohter: " + id);
        }` you can write `this.childCallMe = function(id){ alert('mother' + id) };`. Know that what you did is *basically* the same as the `prototype` way. If you don't like `prototypes` then you might do it this way as well.

Comment: In Javascript you have to explicitly attach functions to objects either via `this.method = function(){ ... };` or via `prototype`. Otherwise it will be visible only inside the object, but invisible from outside.

Comment: Yes, I corrected it to `this.childCallMe = function(id){ alert('mother' + id); };`

Comment: Thank you a lot! I update the code. It's working. Afterwards it's so logical.